# connection failure for some user

Tags: java, sql-server, jboss

I am using JBoss 4.0.5 and MS SQL 2005 in my application, I hope it's not related to MS SQL password "sa" it's logging in properly. But the real problem is when am login in my application with any username its logging in fine. But after 30 mins, some other users trying to logging in from their machine. That time user's can't able to login and we are seeing errors in JBoss console like below. Also our application runs only in intranet.

```
WARN [org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool] Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'.) at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:179) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:565) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.InternalManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(InternalManagedConnectionPool.java:250) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.JBossManagedConnectionPool$BasePool.getConnection(JBossManagedConnectionPool.java:491) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.getManagedConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:341) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.TxConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManager.java:301) at org.jboss.resource.connectionmanager.BaseConnectionManager2.allocateConnection(BaseConnectionManager2.java:396)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"`SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'sa'`"_ - seems pretty explicit to me.

Comment: Hi Jim, Could you please elaborate or explain your pretty explicit idea...Thanks advance

Comment: Do you mean you have this issue when more than 1 user logs-in to your application at the same time?

Comment: Hi Alvin, more than 1 user able to log in in my application,but the problem is after some 20 mins same or different user not able to login again in application??Please help